# Blocks are not highlighting in django vs code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

Is there any extension to do this? It is just not showing any type of highlighting in blocks.

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjT3l.png)

[This is how they look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumrJ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask recommended lecture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable html extension and enable django extension in vscode.
I had that kind of problem.